# Remove text from filename recursively OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, filenames, edit

I need to remove the word 'partial' from a load of email files on OS X 10.6.8 recursively down though a folder tree. Some have the word partial in, some don't.
I came close with this terminal command

```
find . -name '*.partial.emlx' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%}.emlx"' {} \;
```

I say close.....it appended all files with another .emlx - but it was recursive and recognised the wildcard input!!!

Can anyone help modify my script? I'm not a programmer so please keep any replies basic :)

I need to end up with

```
mail/foo/3248324.partial.emlx -> mail/foo/3248324.emlx


mail/bar/8757756.partial.emlx -> mail/bar/8757756.emlx


mail/foo/3248325.emlx -> unchanged
```

Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `find` to output the basis of an appropriate `mv` command:

```
$ find mail -name *.partial.emlx -exec echo mv -v \'{}\' \'{}\' \; 
mv -v 'mail/foo/3248324.partial.emlx' 'mail/foo/3248324.partial.emlx'
mv -v 'mail/bar/8757756.partial.emlx' 'mail/bar/8757756.partial.emlx'
```

Pipe that to `sed` to replace the final instance of `partial.emlx` with `.emlx`:

```
$ find mail -name *.partial.emlx -exec echo mv -v \'{}\' \'{}\' \; | sed "s/partial\.emlx'$/emlx'/"
mv -v 'mail/foo/3248324.partial.emlx' 'mail/foo/3248324.emlx'
mv -v 'mail/bar/8757756.partial.emlx' 'mail/bar/8757756.emlx'
```

At this point, if those commands look sane, you could just copy/paste them — or pipe to `sh` to execute them all.

```
$ find mail -name *.partial.emlx -exec echo mv -v \'{}\' \'{}\' \; | sed "s/partial\.emlx'$/emlx'/" | sh
mail/foo/3248324.partial.emlx -> mail/foo/3248324.emlx
mail/bar/8757756.partial.emlx -> mail/bar/8757756.emlx
```

Your files before:

```
$ tree mail
mail
├── bar
│   └── 8757756.partial.emlx
└── foo
    ├── 3248324.partial.emlx
    └── 3248325.emlx

2 directories, 3 files
```

Your files after:

```
$ tree mail
mail
├── bar
│   └── 8757756.emlx
└── foo
    ├── 3248324.emlx
    └── 3248325.emlx

2 directories, 3 files
```

Comment: Dom! Massive virtual high five. That works a treat. Elegant solution just whacking |sh on the end to activate it. If you're ever in Bristol let me know I owe you several pints.